# How to get rows by a string field that not in a string?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table like this:

Id   Name

1    Test1

2    Test2

3    Test3

And I have a string like 'Test1Test2'
So I want records that Name not in that string like 
Test3.
How can I get this row in sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the **instr** core function e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE instr('Test1Test2',name) < 1;
```

[instr(X,Y)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr)

Or you could use LIKE e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE NOT ('Test1Test2' LIKE '%'||name||'%');
```

[The LIKE, GLOB, REGEXP, and MATCH operators](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)